# Probability for change in allele frequencies by random drift

Tags: probability, combinatorics, markov-chains

A biological population comprises $N$ individuals that reproduce to generate N individuals in the next generation. (Due to the random sampling of the 2 alleles of the offsprings from 2 parents we can assume that the frequency of an allele should remain constant on average.) Every individual can carry $2$ different alleles (gene variants) out of a multitude of possible alleles. Thus, there are $2N$ alleles in the population.

Now we look at one particular allele $A$ and we know that the relative frequency of that allele $A$ is $p_A^{t_1}$ in generation $t_1$. Now we wait $k$ generations and measure in the generation $t_k$ the frequency of the allele $A$ again: $p_A^{t_k}$.

My question is: **How can I calculate the probability for getting $p_A^{t_k}$ if the relative frequency of $A$ was $p_A^{t_1}$ $k$ generations before?**

Let's further assume that every allele has the probability $\mu$ (mutation rate) to be transformed into a new allele in every generation.

Sub question: **What is the probability for the change from $p_A^{t_1}$ to $p_A^{t_k}$ after $k$ generations now?**

Comment: Interesting question but I think it needs some clarification: 1) "random sampling of the 2 alleles of the offsprings ..." - does this mean that if the parents have alleles A and B, and C and D respectively, then an offspring will have a 1 in 4 chance of each of A and C, A and D, B and C, and B and D?  2) "there are 2N alleles in the population" - you don't mean that the 2N are all different, do you?  3) Do you assume that each pair of parents produces exactly 2 offspring, or do you allow that some parents have more offspring than others provided each generation has population N?

Comment: Dear @AdamBailey:
1) Yes, if the parents have (A,B) and (C,D) then the offsprings can have either (A,C), (A,D), (B,C), or (B,D) with equal chance (0.25).
2) No, they don't need to be different. In general, there can be $k$ alleles in the total population, with $k \leq 2N$.
3) Good question. But I'd allow that some parents may produce more and others less than 2 offsprings.
Please let me know if you have other questions ... And thanks for your help!

Comment: If the number of offspring per parent can vary, then the frequency of an allele will not necessarily remain constant on average.  For that to hold another assumption is needed: that the number of offspring per parent is independent of whether or not a parent has that allele (since eg if parents with that allele tend to have more than 2 offspring, the frequency of that allele is likely to increase).

Comment: What do you mean by "calculate the probability for getting $p_A^{t_k}$"?  Are you asking for the probability distribution of the frequency of A in period k, or for particular properties of that distribution, eg mean, standard deviation?

Comment: @AdamBailey Yes, partly. We measure $p_A$ at two time points. The 1st time point is $t_1$ and the 2nd time point is $k$ generations later ($t_k$). Since we know the process that changes $p_A$ over time, it should be possible to derive the frequency distribution of A at $t_k$ (**how does it look like**). However, now let's assume that we measure the frequency at $t_k$ again. Now it is $p_A^{t_k}$. Thus my second question is how can I determine the probability for seeing $p_A^{t_k}$ if we know that $A$ had a frequency of $p_A^{t_k}$ exactly $k-1$ generations earlier (**second question**).

Comment: This is I believe an example of a [Markov chain](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Markov_chain).  I've added that as a tag which may bring it to the attention of people familiar with that topic.  You might consider editing the title as the term "allele" may be off-putting to some.

Comment: Although I don't know how to prove it, my intuition is that, if N and k are large, then the probability that $p^{t_k}_A = p^{t_1}_A$ will be very low (but not zero because the state space is discrete).

Comment: @AdamBailey Hmm, thanks a lot for your efforts and help!